# How to add autoincrement serial number in ui component admin grid?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have created grid using ui component. I want to add column serial number.

I added primary key i.e item_id of table. But if record gets deleted then serial number does not work.

=> Ex : I deleted record 2 then serial number column will display no. 1,3,4,5...

Is there any element which define autoincrement in xml.

```
     <column name="item_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sr No</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

I tried sql query i.e

```
 set @row_number=0;
 select (@row_number := @row_number +1) as num,name from feedback
```

How to implement in magento 2?

```
  echo "set @row_number=0; ";
  $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],'main_table.feedback_id = secondTable.entity_id',['main_table.name','(@row_number := @row_number +1) as num']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code :

```
<column name="item_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column
```

This code will be helpful to you.

Comment: I want to add serial number 1,2,3,4..... . How can be added? Is there any element like autoincrement defined in ui component?

Comment: It's auto increment/primary key field. There is no need to add serial number.

Comment: If I delete record then serial number will display 1,3,4...format

Comment: It's default fuctionality. we can't change it. because it's auto increment field.

Comment: we can delete record from grid or we can add specific condition also for getting specific record. Then at that time how we can use primary key for Serial No.?

Comment: By set primary key field as column name

Comment: @jassi: did you find the solution yet? please post.

Comment: If you found the solution can you please share?